# Why isn't my background script getting executed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I added a simple background script to my Chrome extension.

My `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name" : "Test extension",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "description" : "Test extension.",
  "background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I go to `chrome://extensions` and select `background.js` in `Inspect views`.

It opens devtools where I go to Sources and add a break point to my `background.js`:

```
function foo() {
    return 5;
}
foo(); //break point here
```

Then a reload my extension in `chrome://extensions`.
Nothing happens. The breakpoint is not triggered. 
Is my background script running at all?

Comment: When you reload the extension, does the dev tools window close?

Comment: The problem is that on reload, Dev Tools window becomes detached from the extension.

Comment: @Xan, what exactly do you mean by detached?

Comment: Debugger term - it is no longer connected to the active instance.

Comment: @Xan, not actively connected to active instance of what?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you reload the extension from the extension list, Dev Tools window you opened is not attached to the new background page.

Comment: @Xan, ok. But what about the old instance of the backgroud page. Is it still alive?

Comment: Basically, no. The Dev Tools window staying in this state has been a bug for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIMPLE ANSWER... I struggled with this for a while too...

Once you click `background.html` (or `background.js`), it will open in a SEPARATE debugger window.  At that point, SIMPLY reload it by hitting the `F5` or `CTRL-F5` key(s) from the debugger window (while it is in focus).

**NOTE:**  You *MAY* receive errors about recreating objects that already exist (since they were created when you first clicked on your page(or script)

Answer (score 0):

In order to reload the backgroud page and still keeping your breakpoints, you should switch to console and enter:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better way: call `chrome.runtime.reload()` from the background's console, it's a [documented call](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload) to reload.

I tested it and breakpoints fire.